# How to move search box in-line with top links

Tags: layout, search, header, toplinks

Hoping you can help me with an item. Attached are two screenshots.

**Number 1 My current header**

[image]

**Number 2 - My desired header**

[image]

I am still on a Magento 1.3.1 set up. (I know).

Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is with CSS. If the width of the searchbox is fixed I would position both the toplinks and the searchbox absolute.

Something like

```
.header { position: relative; }
.toplinks { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 150px; }
.searchbox { position: absolute; width: 120px; top: 10px; right: 10px; }
```

Comment: SANDERRRRRR! Thanks so much my friend. That was exactly what I needed. Appreciate the quick response and help!

Comment: hahaha no problem. Don't forget to accept to close. Otherwise we'll have more work on MageStackDay